# swagger has issue with large swagger.json file

Tags: api, swagger, documentation

I have big restful project, and want to document it.
now my team document project with swagger 2.0 but we have 20000 lines in swagger.json and that's a messy and also has some issue with git conflict on swagger.josn.

Can anyone introduce me a new app like swagger with better peformance??

Answer (score 0):

> according to this tutorial we can separate our swagger.json file to
>   multi files:

[install swagger ui and swagger editor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ZK7TsA8a9Q)

Answer (score 0):

Might be too late.

try https://www.npmjs.com/package/apidoc

I feel more comfortable using this as the syntax is easier to under and use in my little experience